# understanding the pandas.MultiIndex.has_duplicates property

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, duplicates

Given a Pandas `MultiIndex` instance `my_index`, I need to detect whether its list-of-tuples representation (i.e., `my_index.tolist()`) contains any duplicate tuples. While this can be done using `len(pandas.unique(my_index)) < len(my_index)`, I was wondering whether the `MultiIndex.has_duplicates` property can be used for this purpose. Although the corresponding unit test in the Pandas source code seems to suggest that this is the case, I'm not sure why the the property is True for the following example which contains no duplicate tuples. (I'm using Pandas 0.15.2 on Linux with Python 2.7.6.) Am I misunderstanding the purpose of the property?

```
import pandas as pd
t = [(u'x', u'out', u'z', 5, u'y', u'in', u'z', 169),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 7, u'y', u'in', u'z', 119),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 9, u'y', u'in', u'z', 135),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 13, u'y', u'in', u'z', 145),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 14, u'y', u'in', u'z', 158),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 16, u'y', u'in', u'z', 122),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 17, u'y', u'in', u'z', 160),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 18, u'y', u'in', u'z', 180),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 20, u'y', u'in', u'z', 143),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 21, u'y', u'in', u'z', 128),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 22, u'y', u'in', u'z', 129),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 25, u'y', u'in', u'z', 111),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 28, u'y', u'in', u'z', 114),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 29, u'y', u'in', u'z', 121),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 31, u'y', u'in', u'z', 126),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 32, u'y', u'in', u'z', 155),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 33, u'y', u'in', u'z', 123),
     (u'x', u'out', u'z', 12, u'y', u'in', u'z', 144)]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(t)
print idx.has_duplicates
```

Comment: It prints False for me.

Comment: What versions of Pandas and Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.8, Pandas 0.15.0

Comment: Confirmed - I also get False when I use Pandas 0.15.0 or 0.14.1 with Python 2.7.6. I'll file an issue report with the developers.

Comment: GitHub issue reference [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/9075).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The developers noted that this is a bug which has been fixed in what will become Pandas 0.16.0.